# How to restrict tolist to a set period of time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using the following linq to be able to get emails to send out. What I want to be able to do is say, email the client on the day of their appointment 30 mins before.  My question is using startdate and enddate fields how would I adjust the query below to allow for this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the allnotes by appointment.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
 public List<tblapertureNetAppointment> getAppointmentsForEmailProccessed()
    {
        try
        {
            var _appointment = apertureNetEntities.tblapertureNetAppointments.Where(f => f.isDeleted == false && f.isProccessed==false ).ToList();
            return _appointment.AsQueryable().ToList();
        }
    catch (Exception ex)

        {
            string inner = string.Empty;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
            }
            logger.Error("Error in IQueryable function getAppointmentsForEmail " + ex.ToString() + " " + inner);
            return null;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Sentences add immeasurably to readability.

Comment: You don't restrict `ToList`, but you can filter collections with the LINQ `Where` extension method, like you're already doing. Just add your date range filtering in there.

Comment: When your `_appointment` is already an in-memory `List<>`, there is no need for `_appointment.AsQueryable().ToList()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume the entity in question has a `DateTime` property called `startTime` that holds the appointment date.

```
public DateTime startTime { get; set;}
```

You need to filter the list based on the appointment start date and time.

```
return _appointment
           .Where(appointment => 
                     (appointment.startTime < Date.Now) &&
                     (appointment.startTime.Date == DateTime.Today) &&
                     (Date.Now - appointment.startTime).TotalMinutes < 30)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: @Nksoi yes it does have a start date and time so thank you that seems to work can that cope with hours ideally i want it to send 24hrs before the time as well on the first pass then 1 hr before the appointment.

Comment: You just need to change the filter to suit the time period you need, be it hours or days.